# How to determine event options?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a simple question that lead to a larger question. I have an OverlayPanel and have to guess what the "hideEvent" option is. The documentation doesn't give out that detail. I downloaded the source and have been filtering through that but so far have been unable to find any list.

Where can I find a list of what the available options are for a primefaces argument when it's not in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's any standard [HTML DOM event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#HTML_events), just part of basic HTML. You know, JSF is merely a HTML code generator.

Comment: I feel a bit silly. I was looking at the Effects and Events synonymously. Thanks